# Is it possible to compute the factorial of a number with a bounded number of exponentiations?

Tags: factorial

We can easily compute the summation of a number N, i.e., `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + N`, with a bounded number of multiplications (`sum(n) = n * (n + 1) * 0.5`). Is it, equivalently, possible to compute the factorial of a number N, i.e., `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * ... * N`, with a bounded number of exponentiations?

Comment: You can get pretty close by Stirling's formula. If you want an exact computation I think it should be impossible.

Comment: The analogy to adding the terms of an arithmetic sequence (such as $1,2,3,\ldots,N$) would be to multiply the terms of a geometric sequence (such as $1,2,4,\ldots,2^N$). The formulas would be closely related. Computing a factorial is like trying to add up a sequence of logarithms of consecutive integers.

Comment: Sadly, my question had a typo, it should be "a bounded number of exponentiations". Does this still apply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no known method to do so. If we had an exact, efficient way to compute $n!$, then we could easily factor any number by just binary searching for factors using Euclid's algorithm.

Specifically, if we wanted to factor a number, $N=pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are large primes, then we could just compute $\text{gcd} (N,k!)$, as we binary search for $k$. We know $k$ is too low if $\text{gcd} (N,k!) =1$, and we know it's too high if $\text{gcd} (N,k!) =N$. Using these two "comparison metrics" we could easily find one of the factors.

However, RSA, a popular security system, relies on the fact that it is computationally impossible to factor numbers of the form $N=pq$. So if you can't break RSA, then you can't quickly compute factorials.

Additionally, if you're looking for an approximation $n! \approx \left( \frac{n}{e} \right) ^n \sqrt{2\pi n}$ is pretty good (this is Stirling's approximation).

Comment: Sadly, my question had a typo, it should be "a bounded number of exponentiations". Does this still apply?

Comment: Yeah, the logic still applies because that would be an efficient way to compute $n!$. This is because there exists a very efficient way to compute exponentiations, which is the exponentiation by squaring method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)